# Displaying "Featured products" or "Recently added products" list in SharePoint site with commerce services

Tags: microsoft-commerce-server

I have a Sharepoint 2007 internet site using Microsoft commerce server 2009.

I need to show a list of "Recently added products" or "featured products". These will be showing products from "all" catalogs.

What is the best approach to implement such requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achive that you could simple run a product search using **LastModified** field to filter recently created products by date.

You'll need to set the catalogs you want to search for, since you said you have to search in all of them.

I believe the code snippet below is what you need. Remember you'll need full-text search up and running to get results from the search.

```
var queryBuilder = 
        new CommerceQuery<Product, CommerceCatalogFullTextSearchBuilder>();

queryBuilder.SearchCriteria.FullTextSearchType = CommerceFullTextSearchType.FreeText;
queryBuilder.SearchCriteria.Catalogs.Add("MyCatalogName1");
queryBuilder.SearchCriteria.Catalogs.Add("MyCatalogName2");
queryBuilder.SearchCriteria.Catalogs.Add("MyCatalogName3");
queryBuilder.SearchCriteria.WhereClause = "LastModified > '2010-10-01'";

CommerceQueryOperationResponse response =
    (CommerceQueryOperationResponse)new OperationServiceAgent()
        .ProcessRequest(requestContext, queryBuilder.ToRequest())
        .OperationResponses[0];

List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
if (response.CommerceEntities != null && response.CommerceEntities.Count > 0)
{
    foreach(var p in response.CommerceEntities)
    {
        products.Add((Product)p);
    }
}

return products;
```